# opencart getSubTotal() function returning price in default currency

Tags: php, opencart, opencart2.x

I'm trying to add statement for different currencies in shipping method. I print the `$this->cart->getSubTotal();` for checking the amount value. Its returning the amount in only default currency.

I have two currencies in admin panel.

1. USD
2. AED (Default)

AED is default in my admin panel so why this function `$this->cart->getSubTotal();` giving me only AED price on all time. Whenever i change the currency to USD through opencart converter then it should not return in AED. So can any one guide me this function always return the price in default currency?

Comment: Hi. Have you tried `$this->currency->convert($this->cart->getSubTotal(), $this->currency->getCode(), $this->config->get('config_currency'));` ?

Comment: I'm not actually sure what do you want to convert to what, so if it's giving the wrong results, you could try swapping the 2nd and 3rd argument.

Comment: @TiborB. yes i tried, but i want to know that this function `$this->cart->getSubTotal()` returning the price in only default currency ?

Comment: What do you mean on default currency? The one set as default on the admin panel, or the one your customer has set as default on the store front?

Comment: @TiborB i total amount is 200 aed and this function `$this->cart->getSubTotal()` alwways returning the amount in  AED. So when i change the currency from currency convertor to USD then why this function give me in same amount 200AED

Comment: @TiborB. Default Currency Means `set as default on the admin panel`